# render_listings() - How to change the font in R input Code?

Tags: r, fonts, knitr

I have a problem by using the "render_listings()"-function in "knitr". In the outputed PDF, I get a formated input section in which the font of relevant symbols, like the arrow or the quote, have been changed. When I copy and paste it to the R console the characters of arrow and quote are changed and are not interpretable for the compiler. So i have to change the symbols back by my own...

How can I change the font of the printed R Input Code?

Following an example that show how helpful the function wraps lines, but also changes the font of the R Input Code.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\lstset{breaklines=true} % break long lines

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@

\begin{document}

Example for a wrap...

<<long-print>>=
x <- c("hdskdfgkgrivklgdm,dsaodfkdf,dfgkgfdilgdfkgdfmbdfklbfdildfkfgm,.fgdklbkub,dgmsgafdsjcvxuikjgsdm,gslibflidfgk.gdfm,.gdfklbcvligdf.gdfk.gdf")
print(x)
@

\end{document}
```

Hopefully, anyone have an idea to help me through...

best regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the LaTeX file generated: that will point you to the `Sweavel.sty` file, 
which specifies how the input and the output are typeset.

In particular, you can add `\ttfamily` to the `basicstyle` to address the quote problem,
and remove the `literate` line to remove the pretty arrows.

Try adding the following to the preamble of your `Rnw` file.

```
\lstdefinestyle{Rstyle}{%
  fancyvrb=false,escapechar=`,language=R,%
  basicstyle={\Rcolor\Sweavesize\ttfamily},%         Added \ttfamily
  backgroundcolor=\Rbackground,%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  keywordstyle=\Rcolor,%
  commentstyle={\Rcommentcolor\ttfamily\itshape},%
  %literate=                                         Removed
  alsoother={$},%
  alsoletter={.<-},%
  otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,/},%
  escapeinside={(*}{*)}}%
```